# Height of a tree - PROLOG

Tags: tree, prolog, height, binary-tree

I try to write a predicate to find the height of a tree in Prolog.

My tree is represented like this:

```
             A
           /    \
          B      C
         / \    / \
        D   E  F   G
```

[a,[b,[d,e],c[f,g]]] ([Root,[Children]])

My predicate is:

```
height(Tr,0) :- 
   atomic(Tr).
height([L|R],N) :- 
   height(L,N1),
   height(R,N2), 
   N is max(N1,N2)+1.
```

But my code doesn't work. When I write :

```
height([a,[b,[d,e],c,[f,g]]],N).
```

N equals 8.

Can I have some help please ?

NB: The height of the root begins at 0.

Comment: Not Working in which dimension?

Comment: Your tree representation doesn't look consistent, and the code you have won't match a valid tree (whatever it looks like - hard to tell what it is). For example, `[c,e,f]` doesn't look like a valid subtree based upon your picture. If that's not what your tree looks like, then please show the actual tree you tested and explain what you mean by, *code doesn't work*.

Comment: I think, first, you need to define a consistent tree representation. `[a,[b,d],[c,e,f]]` (a list of 3 elements) doesn't completely describe the tree you picture, and it doesn't match the general pattern you gave of `[Root, [Children]]` (a list of 2 elements). Once you have a consistent representation, then the code will become straightforward.

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake...
Now I have a consistent tree representation but a bad height :/

Comment: Your new tree representation is still not consistent. If `[a,[b,[d,e],c,[f,g]]]` is a binary tree, then the inside list, `[b, [d,e], c, [f,g]]` has too many elements. The representation should have a clear head, left, right structure to it, and then the predicate can just follow that structure. Right now, your predicate has `[L|R]` where `L` is the list *head* and `R` is the *tail* (the rest of this of list), which doesn't seem right. One would expect symmetry left versus right in the implementation.

Comment: `[a,[b,[d,e],c[f,g]]]` is not a syntactically valid Prolog term which is not term you meant... So, which term *did* you mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It helps to find the right abstraction.

Given a *binary tree* represented using these conventions:

- An *empty tree* is denoted by the atom `nil`.
- A *non-empty tree* is denoted by the structure `tree/3`, where

  - the 1st argument is the node's payload,
  - the 2nd argument is the left subtree (nodes whose payload collates as *less than* that of the current node),
  - the 3rd argument is the right subtree (nodes whose payload collates as *greater than* that of the current node)

The solution is pretty simple:

```
tree_depth( nil         , 0 ) .   % the depth of an empty tree is 0.
tree_depth( tree(_,L,R) , D ) :-  % the depth of a non-empty tree is computed thus:
  tree_depth(L,L1) ,              % - compute the depth of the left subtree
  tree_depth(R,R1) ,              % - compute the depth of the right subtree
  D is 1 + max(L1,R1)             % - the overall depth is 1 more than the maximum depth in both subtrees.
  .                               %
```

Computing the depth of a *n-ary tree* where each node can have an arbitrary number of children, isn't much more complicated. We'll represent our *n-ary tree* thus:

- The *empty tree* is again denoted by the atom `nil`.
- A *non-empty tree* is denoted by a structure `tree/2`, where

  - the 1st argument is the node's payload
  - the 2nd argument is a list containing the node's subtrees (any of which might be `nil`).

The solution is, again, simple:

```
tree_depth( nil       , 0 ) .   % the depth of the empty tree is 0.
tree_depth( tree(_,C) , D ) :-  % the depth of a non-empty tree is computed thus:
  subtree_depth( C , 0 , T ) ,  % - compute the depth of the subtrees of the current node
  D is 1+T                      % - add 1 to that
  .                             %

subtree_depth( []     , D , D ) .   % child subtrees exhausted? unify the accumulator with the result
subtree_depth( [X|Xs] , T , D ) :-  % otherwise...
  tree_depth(X,X1) ,                % - compute the depth of the current subtree
  T1 is max(T,X1) ,                 % - set the accumulator the max value
  subtree_depth( Xs , T1 , D )      % - recurse down on the tail.
  .
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query doesn't seem to represent a valid tree, that should *always* have the shape `[_, SubList]`. This snippet assumes such representation, and availability of library([aggregate](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=aggregate)):

```
height([_,Sub], Height) :- !,
    aggregate(max(H + 1), S^(member(S, Sub), height(S, H)), Height).
height(_, 0).
```

yields

```
?- height([a,[ [b,[d,e]], [c,[f,g]] ]],N).
N = 2.
```